# Does the end user of an asp.net application needs .net installed

Tags: .net, asp.net

When creating a asp.net page, which uses the .NET framework, does the client accessing the page need to have the .NET framework installed on their computer?  I.e. User goes to www.fakesite.com/default.aspx, if they do not have the framework installed will they be able to access the website?

I ask because I'm not sure if the server processes the server-side code and then displays the HTML code to the client in which the client would not need the .NET framework.

Comment: Hi, it's much better if your title reflects the question. SEO way and stackoverflow-search way.

Comment: Yea, Sorry, it was kind of spur of the moment question.

Comment: Ahhh, I look back on this question when I was a wee entry level programmer.  The memories :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because your client recieves only Html Css and javascript on the other hand the server will need the proper version of .net installed and to be hosted on IIS and if you use MsSql you will need it to be installed

also asp.net adds a hidden input in your html called viewstate to keep the state of the session over the Http protocol

Answer (score 11):

The client doesn't need to have .net framework installed. ASP.NET is server side technology.

Answer (score 5):

No - what the client gets back is HTML (plus maybe some JS, CSS, and the like), not .NET. Same goes true if you have a user go to a JSP page.  They don't need Java installed to view, though Java is used on the server to render the pages.

Answer (score 3):

They do not need to have the framework installed to view a website made with the .NET framework